# In probability identical items are treated like distinct items?

Tags: combinations, probability

if we have 3 green identical balls and 5 red identical balls
The probability of green ball is 3C1/8C1.
But according to combinatrics the num of ways to select one ball out of 8 balls is 2,either green or red.
And to choose one green ball out of green ball is 1.
But in probability we treat indentical balls as they are distinct.

Comment: You keep saying "indentical" - do you mean "identical" ?   If so, given 3 green and 5 red, then the probability of drawing a green is indeed 3/8.  The "num of ways to ... is 2" is clearly incorrect - imagine more options, like the probability of drawing the Ace of Spades from a standard deck of cards - you wouldn't say "the number of ways is 2, either AceOfSpades or Not-AceOfSpades".   For more discussion, I'd go to https://math.stackexchange.com/ , since here at stackoverflow.com is really for programming questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and should be on math exchange site.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and depending on the assumption about distinguishability, you'll get different results. A related problem is, when you're counting atoms in different states, are they distinguishable or indistinguishable? I seem to recall one way you get Bose-Einstein statistics and the other you get Fermi-Dirac (I may have mixed up the names and/or concepts). Anyway whether the balls are distinguishable is part of the problem statement -- sometimes they are, sometimes not. For further discussion, try this question on stats.stackexchange.com.